# Changing the id-attribute of a list item with jquery

Tags: jquery

When I click on the list-item below (li) I change the id of it from sprite-heart to sprite-stars. That works nice.

But once I click the li again it handles the function like it is sprite-heart but the function should be bypassed now that the list item is sprite-stars.

How can I change this?

```
<li><a class="navit" id="sprite-heart" title="Love this webcam! Add to my personal webcam page" href="#"><span class="love">Love this webcam</span></a></li>




    $("#sprite-heart").click(function() {

    addfavcam();

    });

    function addfavcam()
    {


   $.ajax({
        url: '/v3/ajax/addfavourite.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: <?php echo $cam_id; ?>, usr: 'x<?php echo $user_id; ?>'},
        success: function(responseText){


    $('#sprite-heart').attr('id','sprite-stars');
    $('#sprite-heart,#sprite-stars').attr('title','My favourite');

        },
        error: function(responseText){
        }
    });

    }
```

Comment: Changing the ID attribute doesn't work reliably across browsers iirc

Comment: As a side-note: Ids of elements have to be unique on a page, changing ids dynamically is increasing the risk of ending up with elements having the same id, which in turn is invalid html and has unwanted side-effects. If you would like to indicate state or indicate something else on an element, use a class, custom attribute or `$(selector).data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to unbind the event, not just change the id. just add

```
 $("#sprite-heart").click(function() { $(this).unbind('click'); ... }
```